# Reduce runtime in java 8

Tags: java, stream, runtime

My program processes a file with about 2500 words.
I want to get the number of lines that contain both words from the file.
I've written the following code for this. This program requires about 3 hours to run!
According to my research, the reason for the high runtime is to use stream. How can I reduce runtime?

```
Stream<String> fileLines = Files.lines(ngramPath, Charset.defaultCharset());
    Supplier<Stream<String>> SfileLines = () -> {
        try {
            return Files.lines(ngramPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileLines;
    };
while (reviews1.hasNext()) 
    {
        String term_i = reviews1.next();
        reviews2= new Scanner(path);
        while(reviews2.hasNext())
            {
                String term_j = reviews2.next();
                if (!term_i.equals(term_j))
                {
                    double pij = (double) SfileLines.get().filter(s -> s.contains(term_i+" ") & s.contains(term_j+" ")).count();
                    term_i_Ass.put(term_j, pij);
                }
            }
            Total.put(term_i, term_i_Ass);
        }
```

UPDATE: The part that has more time to run is the following code:

```
double pij = (double) SfileLines.get().filter(s -> s.contains(term_i+" ") & s.contains(term_j+" ")).count();
```

I need to write this line of the program in a different way, which requires less time.

Comment: For a start, it looks like you're reading the file every time you iterate through the loop.

Comment: changing `&` to short circuiting operator `&&` should also help.

Comment: read the file once into a `List<String>` and then Stream the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

[BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) is as fast as you need: you can read millions of lines a second with it.

Example of usage:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader fr = null;

try {

        //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;

        while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null){
                br.close();
            }
            if (fr != null){
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you want to use the `Stream`, try with:

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("path to file"))) {

        stream.forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The first code snippet is basically exactly what `Files.lines` is doing under the hood.

Comment: Not at all. This method does not read all lines, it populates lazily as the stream is consumed, so, if i don't consume the Stream, I don't read the lines.

Comment: But that's also what `Files.lines` does - it produces a stream of lines that are lazily read from the file (via `BufferedReader.lines` FWIW).

Comment: This is what I am saying. Files.lines read all lines lazily, but the first code snippet don't do lazy anything. It read only line by line. In the case of Files.lines you read all the lines and need to iterate over the stream to take it.